# Remove number demical and turn into hexadecimal

Tags: c++, iomanip

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T; cin >> T;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::uppercase);
    cout << setw(0xf) << internal;
    while (T--) {
        double A; cin >> A;
        double B; cin >> B;
        double C; cin >> C;

        cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << hex << showbase << A << '\n';
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpos << right << setfill('_') << setw(15) << B << '\n';
        cout << fixed << setprecision(9) << scientific << C;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

This is the problems that I can't solve:

- I want to turn number `A` into a hexadecimal number (including the `0x` prefix) and remove its decimal.

  Ex: A = 1345.6454 => I just take 1345 and remove 6454.
- In the output of the above code, number `C` displays a `+` sign and I want to remove it.

Does someone know how to solve these problems?

Comment: On a side note: `cout << setiosflags(ios::uppercase)` can be simplified to `cout << uppercase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed:

> Hexadecimal floating-point formatting ignores the stream precision specification, as required by the specification of [`std::num_put::do_put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put).

To truncate the decimal off of a floating-point number, cast the value to an integer, eg:

```
cout << hex << showbase << static_cast<int>(A) << '\n';
```

---

Per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put:

> For both integer and floating-point types, if `showpos` is set, the modifier `+` is prepended

And per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf:

> `+`: the sign of signed conversions is always prepended to the result of the conversion (by default the result is preceded by minus only when it is negative)

You have enabled `showpos` when printing `B`, and it is still enabled when printing `C`.

You can use [`std::resetiosflags(std::ios::showpos)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags) or [`std::noshowpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpos) to disable `showpos`:

```
cout << resetiosflags(ios::showpos) << fixed << setprecision(9) << scientific << C;
```

```
cout << noshowpos << fixed << setprecision(9) << scientific << C;
```

Comment: But in the ouput number A appears like this: 0x[spaces]64.

Comment: I want erase this spaces. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Quanghuynh You are using `std::setw` and `std::internal` before printing `A`. The spaces are the padding that `operator<<` adds to fill in the specified width. By default, `std::internal` makes `operator<<` print the prefix to the left of the padding. Then the hex value is being printed to the right of the padding. Drop `std::internal` or add `std::right` to move the prefix to the right side. I suggest you read [`std::num_put::put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) for the various ways that I/O manipulators affect output.